# Scoops app background scolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, parallax

The popular iPhone game called [Scoops](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/scoops-ice-cream-fun-for-everyone/id291591378?mt=8) has cool scrolling backgrounds. I am currently working with cocos2d and I was wondering how a similar sort of scrolling background could be achieved?

It seems like they are just using an extremely long background image, but supposedly you could play forever. How do you scroll a large background image in cocos2d, would you just keep reseting its position.

Is there anyway to have a bit more lightweight parallax node or something similar, but that still could transition from sky to space at some point?

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My article about [scrolling with cocos2d](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/12/ways-scrolling-cocos2d-explained/) should answer your question. I take an educated guess and say they used the first approach which I dub "fake scrolling" where scrolling is only seemingly endless because the scrolling background's position is reset regularly.